# Add specified tests in sfdx deploy command

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin

I want to use specified test classes available in my repository with sfdx force deploy command. I can include it using -l RunSpecifiedTests -r TestClass1,TestClass2.
However, I had to manually write the test class name in case of any additions. Can there be any such parameter in sfdx or some other way I can import all test cases present in the repository so that while running in prod it only runs the specified ones.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no.

If you want to select specific tests to be run in a deployment, you currently must explicitly type them all out in the `-r` flag.

It'd be nice if we had the ability to specify a test suite to run (on deployment). From what I recall though, sfdx is just an interface that wraps the metadata api (so getting test suite support would also require the metadata api team, which is a separate team, to also do work).

+edit: references
https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/621 (is a wrapper for the metadata api)
https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1836 (possibly being worked on at time of writing?)

Comment: Oddly, you can run suites (which also uses mdapi) via `sf apex test run --suite-names`, but apparently isn't an option for deploys. I guess one could write a script for it, though.